# Boostrap Collapse <table>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide a part of a table using bootstraps `collapse` method.

It works okay except that it applies `display:block` to the table, which makes the table display in an incorrect way after it's toggled.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href='#' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#hiddenFooter'>Toggle</a>

<table class='table table-condensed table-hover'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Today</td>
      <td>Is</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Good</td>
      <td>Day</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot id='hiddenFooter' class='collapse'>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer</td>
      <td>Fotir</td>
      <td>Finner</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer</td>
      <td>Fitter</td>
      <td>Fatter</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Even if I toggle an entire table (and not a `tfoot`) the results are the same.  There must be a way to do this in bootstrap without writing my own jQuery code.

Comment: I don't think there is, the problem is that when you toggle it, then it get `Display:block or none`, But it needs `display: table-footer-group;`

Comment: yes, just overwriting css class  as .collapse.in {display: table-footer-group;} should work.

Comment: @Archana That might work in this case, but he has to be sure that it dont affect other places where it should not, so maybe `table .collapse.in {display: table-footer-group;}`

Comment: @Archana no that didnt work, but adding `!important` to your `collapse.in` class did! If you want to post it as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: @Chud37 Thanks much:) Now Carsten Løvbo Andersen has already posted the answer so I am not posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Archana said, use `.collapse.in {display: table-footer-group}` but to make sure you don't change the normal `.collapse.in` except for the `tfoot` then use `table tfoot.collapse.in {display: table-footer-group;}` or `table #hiddenFooter.collapse.in {display: table-footer-group;}

Example below

```css
table #hiddenFooter.collapse.in {display: table-footer-group;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href='#' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#hiddenFooter'>Toggle</a>

<table class='table table-condensed table-hover'>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Today</td>
    <td>Is</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Good</td>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot id='hiddenFooter' class='collapse'>
  <tr>
    <td>Footer</td>
    <td>Fotir</td>
    <td>Finner</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Footer</td>
    <td>Fitter</td>
    <td>Fatter</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

`

Comment: It only worked for me when I used `!Important`, I dont know why it works for you without it.

Comment: @Chud37 It can be something to do with some other css you have in your page, css link order on the page. But if it works with `!important` just go with it, but you might want to take my example and make it more specific to the table